# Two way binding for TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

This question was asked here for thousands times.
But really, none of your examples and answers works for me.
So let me show you my code.

```
public class PlayList : INotifyPropertyChanged{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private string _dl;
    public string DriveLetter {
        get { return _dl; }
        set {
            if (value != _dl) {
                _dl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DriveLetter");
            }
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public PlayList playlist = new PlayList();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Binding bind = new Binding("DriveLetter");
        bind.Source = this.playlist;
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        textBox1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);

        this.playlist.DriveLetter = "A";
    }
}
```

Ofcourse WPF ignores this binding (nothing changes when I type in textbox, and nothing changes when I change playlist.DriveLetter property.

Debugger says, that PropertyChanged handler is not null

```
{Method = {Void OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)}}
```

So, any ideas what I am doing wrong. (I do not belive that WPF is wrong)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are building the binding in code instead of XAML? And have you tried using tools like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for debugging the bindings, or have you tried setting breakpoints in your property to see if any code execution is taking place there?

Comment: Yes, there is quite good reason. I want to use playlist object later in code.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a good reason to do it this way.

Comment: You can declare your `Playlist` object in code while setting it as the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`, or simply provide a property for it that the XAML can refer to for it's source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
textBox1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);
```

to

```
textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to do it this way, even if you want to use your playlist later on.
Just use a Property in your Window like:

```
public PlayList PlayList
{
  get;
  private set;
}
```

and Bind your TextBox like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlayList.DriveLetter}"/>
```

you also have to set the DataContext of the Window, I think:

```
DataContext = this;
```

or you set the Data Context to your PlayList:

```
DataContext = PlayList;
```

so the Binding looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DriveLetter}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
 textBox1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);
```

to

```
 textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
```

You are binding `TextBlock's` text property rather than `TexBox's` text property

Comment: I am really sorry. Really sorry for my blindness (too fast typing + InteliSense). I'm going to Castorama to buy some rope. 2 Days wasted.